# Read php file into text file

Tags: php, file, text

## My Code is

```
$check=  get_text22('http://localhost:81/ci/',$numb);
file_put_contents('fail.txt', $check, FILE_APPEND);

function get_text22($filename,$id){
    $context=...
    $fp_load = fopen("$filename", "rb",false,$context);
    if ( $fp_load ){
        while ( !feof($fp_load) ){
            $content .= fgets($fp_load, 8192);
        }
        fclose($fp_load);
        return $content;
    }
}
```

## Generate File fail.txt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="ci/assets/favicon.ico">
   ...
```

But This generate html file. I want it can generate php file without process how it written at server in `<?php` tag.

Comment: You can't read source of php file through http protocol. You get result of execution

Comment: It's impossible. You can get such source only on server where your code working, setting absolute path to file

Comment: What is your issue; is it that your output doesn't contain PHP code or that your out? Or something else? Please clarify your question

Comment: I want Php file, Without process from server

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Read the PHP file from your filesystem instead of the URL of the results of executing the PHP from your HTTP server.
2. Configure the HTTP server running on `localhost:81` to serve up PHP source code instead of executing it. i.e. Do the **opposite** of what [this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/19068).

The first of those two options is the sensible one.